# Navigation Bar Height

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a view that I whipped up in Interface Builder which has some content and a nav bar at the top. Typically throughout the iPhone UI, when the device is rotated to landscape, the nav bars get slightly shorter (in height). However, mine stays the same when rotated in any orientation. Is this some quirk about doing it through IB or am I missing a property somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Have you added the navigation bar manually?

Comment: Via IB. I did not [[UINavigationController alloc] init, anywhere

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is the `autoresizingMask` of the `UINavigationBar` that you've added via IB. You need to change it but IB unfortunately (maybe a bug) doesn't allow us to add the `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` option. So you will need to do it programmatically,

```
navBar.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, a `UIToolbar` will stay the same size. If your `viewController` is of `UINavigationController` class, the height of the bar should conform to rotation.

Comment: It is definitely a Navigation Bar and not a Toolbar.. How can I fix this issue then?

Comment: To be more specific .. a navigationBar? Or a UINavigationController?

Comment: I simply added a navigation bar in IB.

Comment: This may be your issue. Try making your view a UINavigationController.